# Must declare the scalar variable table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @HospitalReport TABLE (Registrator VARCHAR (20))

INSERT INTO @HospitalReport (Registrator) 
VALUES("64")

SELECT 
    @HospitalReport.Registrator 
FROM 
    @HospitalReport

IF Registrator > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Database.dbo.Users.Firstname, Database.dbo.Users.Lastname 
    FROM 
        StradaAnv.dbo.Anvandare 
    WHERE 
        Id = Registrator

    IF Firstname != NULL AND Lastname != NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @HospitalReport 
        SET Registrator = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname 
        WHERE Registrator = Registrator
    END 
END

SELECT * FROM @HospitalReport
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@HospitalReport"

What I see, I already have declared `@HospitalReport` as a table?

Comment: use **aliases** for tables

Comment: Also, you **cannot** compare against `NULL` with the standard equality and non-equality operators - you **must use** `FirstName IS NULL` (or `IS NOT NULL`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't split everything out into procedural steps. Tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*:

```
DECLARE @HospitalReport TABLE (Registrator VARCHAR (20))

INSERT INTO @HospitalReport (Registrator) 
VALUES("64")

UPDATE H  
SET Registrator = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname
FROM
    @HospitalReport H
        INNER JOIN
    StradaAnv.dbo.Anvandare A
        ON
           H.Registrator = A.Registrator
WHERE A.Firstname IS NOT NULL AND
      A.Lastname IS NOT NULL

SELECT * FROM @HospitalReport
```

I.e. I'm not first querying the table. Then seeing whether particular columns are not null<sup>1</sup>. Then deciding whether or not to perform an update. I'm describing the *entire* operation in a single query and then letting the optimizer work out how best to perform this task.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which, as shown above, should be done using the `IS NULL` operator rather than `!=` since `NULL` is neither equal not not equal to `NULL`